# Printing the multi layer Perceptron ANN prediction value in the data frame

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am the beginner to tensor flow and need to 
get the predicted value (if customer will subscribe the term deposit or not) as the output (in data frame format) for Multi-Perception ANN Model for given data frame as the input.. 
for Banking Campaign..
We are referring this sample 
https://github.com/ManikandanJeyabal/Workplace/blob/master/ANN/TensorFlow/BankMarketing.py

We have tried to run this in notebooks  on Azure  virtual machine  with Python 3.6

In above sample , we will need to modify the source code below to get the predictions (in the form of data frame , so that it can be displayed as the report.)

````
plt.plot(mse_his, 'r')
plt.show()
plt.plot(accu_his)
plt.show()

# print the final accuracy
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
print("Test Accuracy--> ", (sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y_: y_test})))

# print final mean square error
pred_y = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: x_test})
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred_y - y_test))
print("MSE: %.4f" % sess.run(mse))
print(correct_pred)


print(y_test)  ```

we need to get the output in the form of panadas dataframe along with the predicted columns?

Please guide me here

----------------------------------------------
Updates:
Thank you for the response,McAngus.. 
After the changes in comments below.. I could render the dataframe output but with this output , How can I derive True or False Predicted Value?
[Dataframe Output][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8iJ9.png
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to put the results in a data frame. From [here](https://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html) you can use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` like so:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"target": y_test.tolist(), "prediction": pred_y.tolist()})
```

This will give the column headers `target` and `prediction`.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"target": y_test, "prediction": pred_y})
#dict_test = {"target": y_test, "prediction": pred_y}
#df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(dict_test.items()), columns = ['target','prediction'])
#df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"target": y_test, "prediction": pred_y}, orient = 'index')
df.head(). This turns into the error : -->If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: You might have to convert the numpy arrays to lists (i've updated the answer).